# Expectation of a mixed random variable

Tags: expectation, conditional-expectation

My goal is to derive the expected value of the mixed random variable $\min(T_x,n)= \begin{cases} 
      T_x & \text{for} \ \ T_x \leq n \\
      n & \text{for} \ \ T_x > n
   \end{cases}$
where $n \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $n > 0$ (i.e. $\min(T_x,n)$ has a density over $(0,n)$ and a probability mass at $n$).

My approach was to derive it using the Law of Total Expectation:
$E[\min(T_x,n)] = E[T_x|T_x \leq n] \cdot P(T_x \leq n) + E[n|T_x > n] \cdot P(T_x > n) = \\ E[T_x|T_x \leq n] \cdot P(T_x \leq n) + n \cdot P(T_x > n)$

$P(T_x \leq n)$ and $P(T_x > n)$ are known (CDF / survival function) but the problem is to derive $E[T_x|T_x \leq n] = \int_0^n[t \cdot f_{T_x|T_x \leq n}(t)]dt$, i.e. to derive $f_{T_x|T_x \leq n}(t)$.

Since $f$ is a probability **density** function (pdf) we can write $f_{T_x|T_x \leq n}(t)=\frac{f_{T_x,T_x \leq n}(t)}{f_{T_x \leq n}(t)}$ but I have no clue what to do next.

Is this approach correct so far (and the most handy) and if it is, how to continue?

Comment: I suspect $E[T_x|T_x\le n]P(T_x\le n) =\int_0^n tf_{T_x}(t)dt$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg That's correct but how can one show this using probability theory? In the proof suggestion they derive $f_{T_x|T_x \leq n}(t)$ separately but they use arguments based on $T_x$ being a discrete random variable but $T_x$ is continuous, so that's not correct.

Comment: You use the notation $f_{T_x,T_x\le n}(t)$. I wouldn't know how to define it.  However, I believe it is nothing more than $f_{T_x}(t)$ when $t\le n$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Okay. Why you wrote $E[T_x|T_x \leq n]P(T_x \leq n) = \int_0^n[t f_{T_x}]dt$ then and not 'just' $E[T_x|T_x \leq n] = \int_0^n[t f_{T_x}(t)]dt$? That's what I would write (by applying the definition of mathematical expectation). $P(T_x \leq n)$ is a known CDF.

Comment: \begin{align}
\mathbb E[T_x\wedge n] &= \mathbb E[T_x\wedge n\mathsf 1_{\{T_x\leqslant n\}}] + \mathbb E[T_x\wedge n\mathsf 1_{\{T_x>n\}}]\\
&= \mathbb E[T_x\mathsf 1_{\{T_x\leqslant n\}}] + n\mathbb E[\mathsf 1_{\{T_x>n\}}]\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^n s\ \mathsf dT_x(s) + n\mathbb P(T_x>n).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same question in my assignment. I looked for existing formulas online but got none. So I had to derive it by myself. It has been four years since you asked this question. But I hope that my answer can still help some people who are suffering from it.

Based on your description, I assume $T_x$ is also non-negative. But it does not matter much if it is not. The main idea of my answer will not change.

**When we find it hard to obtain the pdf, we may go back to the cdf.** Let's derive $F_{T_x|T_x \leq n}(t)$ first.

\begin{align*}
F_{T_x|T_x \leq n}(t) &= \textbf{Pr}(T_x \leq t |T_x \leq n)\\
&= \frac{\textbf{Pr}(\{T_x \leq t\} \cap \{T_x \leq n\})}{\textbf{Pr}(T_x \leq n)}\\
&= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{\textbf{Pr}(T_x \leq t)}{\textbf{Pr}(T_x \leq n)}, & \text{if } n > t\\
1, & \text{if } n \leq t
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{F_{T_x}(t)}{F_{T_x}(n)}, & \text{if } n > t\\
1, & \text{if } n \leq t
\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}

Now we can take the derivative of the cdf to get the pdf. Some people may doubt its differentiability at $t = n$. But we can prove that the derivative exists by the definition.Then we have the pdf.

\begin{equation*}
f_{T_x|T_x \leq n}(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{f_{T_x}(t)}{F_{T_x}(n)}, & \text{if } n > t\\
0, & \text{if } n \leq t
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Finally, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[T_x|T_x \leq n] &= \int_{0}^{n} t\frac{f_{T_x}(t)}{F_{T_x}(n)} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{F_{T_x}(n)}\int_{0}^{n} tf_{T_x}(t) \, dt
\end{align*}

It's so late at night that I don't even want to check whether there are typos. But I believe I have presented all key ideas. The comment left by @Math1000 is also a nice  way to solve your question, where you don't need to find the pdf of $T_x|T_x \leq n$.